# How to get the "navgrid" parameter

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

How can I get the 'navGrid' option parameters ?

e.g. : If I define the 'navGrid' like that... :

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#myNavGrid', {
    edit : true,
    edittitle : "edit",
    editfunc : _editRow, // a custom function
});
```

... how can I get the 'editfunc' function (or the 'edittitle' value) in an other part of my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way to get parameters used for `navGrid` like parameters of the most other options which you used as parameters of other functions. I don't really understand *why* you could need it. You can just save the parameters in a variable defined somewhere in outer block and use it whenever you need it:

```
var navGridOptions = {
        edit : true,
        edittitle : "edit",
        editfunc : _editRow, // a custom function
    };
....
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#myNavGrid', navGridOptions);

// you can use here navGridOptions one more time
```